# Read user input before update in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I separate a script to manage user input in unity3d, so the character itself can controlled not necessarily by user input, and also by AI.

Question is: I want other logic script to read input from this script named `InputManager` like `InputManage ipt; ipt.walk ipt.jump`. How can I guarantee that the input is updated before other update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general is a good thing (and a design) choice, not to rely on script execution order.

By the way it's possible to force some script to update in a specific order. You can modify that in [Edit->Project Settings->Script Execution Order](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-ScriptExecution.html).

Comment: Yes, I find that. Btw: I've seen your profile, note that you are an expert in both network and unity3d. So I have a game client designed using unity3d, and I receive message from server. When I received a message I have a `Dispatcher` to handle message in it's `Update`, it first see the type of the message, and according to the type of message, it will dispatch the message to an appropriate handler say `handle_login`, `handle_something` whatever which is all defined in a class that is not derived from `MonoBehaviour`. Frequently, I need to Instantiate a new GameObject in the handler.

Comment: But the `Handler` class contains all handler is not derived `MonoBehaviour`, I can't Instantiate new Object in it. How to make this work while keep the framework of message dispatch and handle?

Comment: GameObject.Instantiate is a static method. You can call it from a class which isn't a MonoBehavior, can't you?

Answer (score 0):

Reading input -> Update (https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html)
Character (and other scripts using your Input) -> LateUpdate (https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html)

This ensures that the input is processed before updating the character or other game objects.

Comment: I don't think putting all other updating in LateUpdate is a good idea. It's not designed to do such a thing.